# android Sqllite : how to set the limit of rows in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to limit the number of rows in x table. Let say in x table have 3 records r1, r2 and r3 when new record is available for insertion then r3 should be deleted and new record should be added so the total number of rows always remain 3 ...

Comment: You can run delete query and then run the insert query for new record.

Comment: Or simply **update** the last record, instead of deleting and reinserting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need LRU Disk (Last recently used) mechanism. There are lots of LRU libraries that can read and write from disk. Here is a [one](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) of them.